# can't use eloquent ::query() on Laravel controller

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to do a dinamic chained query so im using the `query()` method, but i'm getting null/empty result I tested it using `php artisan tinker` and works well but in controller doesn't

```
$item = Item::query();

$item->where('active', true);

if($request->control_negative_stock){

 $item->where('stock', '>', 0);

}

$item->get();
```

I imported `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;` class in both model and controller but still doesn't work

Comment: You can run `$item->toSql()` instead of `$item->get()` to see the Query being executed, and use a SQL Tool to compare results against expected outcome. Or `DB::enableQueryLog()` at the top of your file, then `dd(DB::getQueryLog())` at the bottom to see your full query stack. I agree with John, your query looks fine, there likely aren't any results in your DB, or your 2nd `->where()` isn't being included due to `$request->control_negative_stock` being `false`-y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure your query satisfies where conditions.Then you should store your conditional query in variable.

```
$item = Item::query();

$item->where('active', true);

if($request->control_negative_stock){

 $item->where('stock', '>', 0);

}

$result=$item->get();
```

if you `dd($result);` then you get all data

if you `dd($item->get())` then it will show all data if your query satisfies specified condition.

But it fails to return result if you `dd($item);`

Comment: @SantiagoRamirez.glad that it solved your issue

Answer (score 0):

I know this has already been answered and accepted, but I will just share a small tip for better code:

```php
$result = Item::where('active', true)
    ->when($request->control_negative_stock, function ($query) {
        return $query->where('stock', '>', 0);
    })
    ->get();
```

There is no need to do `$item = Item::query();` and then `$item->where(....)`. Also, take advantage of [`when`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses), so you can avoid `if`s and you can directly have a seamless query.